# Flights as vectors - Where do they intersect?

Tags: calculus, analysis, vectors

We have a flight description and we want to write this as vectors.

Fligh1 : When we go from $A$ (which is on the origin) to $B$ which is $100$ km east and $30$ km south of $A$ then do we have the vector for this flight $(100,-30)-(0,0)=(100,-30)$ ?

Flight2 : When we go from $C$ to $D$, where $C$ is $60$ km east and $90$ km north to origin and $D$ is $40$ km east and $50$ km south to origin. Then do we have the vector for this flight $(40,-50)-(60,90)=(-20,-140)$ ?

Is this correct to write these vectors in 2D ?

Let's suppose that we flight on height $h$. I want to find the coordinates of the point where the two flight routes intersect.

I thought the following but this is not correct :

Since both flights are on height $h$ we consider the 3D vectors $\vec{F1}=\begin{pmatrix}100 \\ -30 \\ h \end{pmatrix}$ and $\vec{F2}=\begin{pmatrix}-20 \\ -140 \\ h\end{pmatrix}$.

Let $P=\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\ h\end{pmatrix}$ be the intersection point.

The vectors of the flights from their starting point to that point are :  $\vec{F1_{AP}}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ h \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0  \\ h\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\vec{F2_{CP}}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ h  \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}65 \\ 89 \\ h\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x-60 \\ y-90 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

We have that $\vec{F2_{CP}}-\vec{F1_{AP}}=\vec{AC}$, where $\vec{AC}$ is the vector from $A$ to $C$, so $\vec{AC}=\begin{pmatrix}60 \\ 90 \\ h \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ h \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}60 \\ 90 \\ h \end{pmatrix}$.

Then $\vec{F2_{CP}}-\vec{F1_{AP}}=\vec{AC}$ i.e. $\begin{pmatrix}x-60 \\ y-90 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}60 \\ 90 \\ h \end{pmatrix}$.

But this is trivial. So my idea is wrong.

Could you give me a hint?

$$$$

**EDIT** :

I have also an other question : Is the flight plane using vectors the following ? $$E: \ \vec{x}=\vec{A}+r\cdot \vec{F1}+s\cdot \vec{F2}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ h \end{pmatrix}+r\cdot \begin{pmatrix}100 \\ -30 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+s\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-20 \\ -140 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: All of your statements are correct, but as you discovered, they do not yet include a solution to the problem. Try writing the equations of the line $AB$ in parameterized format with vectors, and do this also for the line $CD.$ Now you should have something non-trivial to solve.

Comment: Thank you!! I got this now. I have added two more questions in the edit part of my question above. Could you take a look at them? @DavidK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current point $M$ of line $AB$ is such that :

$$\vec{AM}=t \vec{AB}\tag{1}$$

for a certain $t$. Relationship (1) can be written:

$$M-A=t \vec{AB} \ \iff \ M=A+t\vec{AB}$$

In coordinates (you have done these calculations):

$$\pmatrix{x\\y}=t\pmatrix{100\\-30}$$

Said otherwise:

$$\begin{cases}x&=&t(100)\\y&=&t(-30)\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

Now, the second line $CD$. Its current point $N$ of  is such that :

$$\vec{CM}=u \vec{CD}\tag{3}$$

for a certain $u$. Relationship (3) can be written:

$$M-C=u \vec{CD} \ \iff \ M=C+u\vec{CD}$$

In coordinates (you have done these calculations):

$$\pmatrix{x\\y}=\pmatrix{60\\90}+u\pmatrix{-20\\-140}$$

which is equivalent to:

$$\begin{cases}x&=&60+u(-20)\\y&=&90+u(-140)\end{cases}\tag{4}$$

Now express, using (2) and (4), that for a certain $t$ and a certain $u$, points $M$ and $N$ are in fact a same point with the same $x$ and $y$ coordinates :

$$\begin{cases}t(100)&=&60+u(-20)\\t(-30)&=&90+u(-140)\end{cases},\tag{5}$$

which is a system of 2 linear equations with two unknowns that I let you solve.

Don't forget afterwards to check your result on a graphical representation of the "scene".

Remark: the third coordinate isn't necessary in this issue.

Comment: Why do we use vectors in 2D and not 3D, although we have a height of $h$ ? Isn't the height the third coordinate?

Comment: I have also an other question : Is the flight plane using vectors the following ? $$E: \ \vec{x}=\vec{A}+r\cdot \vec{F1}+s\cdot \vec{F2}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ h \end{pmatrix}+r\cdot \begin{pmatrix}100 \\ -30 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+s\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-20 \\ -140 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Answer to your questions : 1) There is no interest to add the burden of a third coordinate if it is always the same ! 2) Yes for the plane. 3) Was my answer clear ? Have you obtained solutions $t$ and $u$ ?

Comment: Was my answer useful ? Have you checked that replacing $t$ in equation (2), or $u$ in equation (4) gives you the same point, which is the intersection point ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! :-)